# Terminal Server IE Reset

Tags: terminal-server, internet-explorer-8

Is there anyway I can reset the Advanced security settings in IE8 for all users on a 2003 terminal server without using group policy?

We are having a issue with Enhanced security showing enabled for most users but Enhanced security is not currently installed. So far resetting the security settings back to default seems to clear this.

Anyone know of another way?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

Open notepad, and copy/paste the following into the file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"IEHardenIENoWarn"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap]
"IEHarden"=dword:00000000
```

Save the file as "IEHardenFix.reg" in a directory that all users have access to.  In my case, I used my "Scripts" directory, but the %systemroot%\system32 works too.

Then, modify %systemroot%\system32\usrlogon.cmd.  At the end, after the line that contains ":DONE" add a new line that looks like this:

```
regedit /s "%systemroot%\system32\IEHardenFix.reg"
```

Save and close the usrlogon.cmd file.

Now, when the users log on, this reg file will be silently imported into their registry, disabling the Enhanced Security Configuration for that user.

Hope this helps,

Glenn